Finding $f''(-2)$ of a power series
I was given a two part question in which i was given the function
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(n+2)(x+2)^n}{n(2^{3n})}$$(1)

Find the radius of convergence $R$ of the power series that defines $f$ in (1).

in which i found the interval to be $(-10,6)$ and radius $R=8$
The second part was: 2. What is the value of $f''(-2)$?
i keep getting $f''(-2) = 0$ but the answer is $f''(-2) = 1/16$
i first took the first derivative which ended up being
$$f'(x)=  \frac{(n+2)(x+2)^{n-1}}{(2^{3n})}$$
and second derivative being
$$f''(x)=  \frac{(n+2)(n-1)(x+2)^{n-1}}{(2^{3n})}$$
in which you plug in x=-2
$$f''(-2)=  \frac{(n+2)(n-1)(0)^{n-1}}{(2^{3n})}$$
since the 0^n-1 would result in the series equaling to 0 i read somewhere that you plug in the first value of n which is n=1 and if you got 0^0 that would equal to 1 but for my case i still get
$$f''(-2)=  \frac{(1+2)(1-1)(0)^{0}}{(2^{3})}$$
$$f''(-2)=  \frac{3(0)(1)}{8}$$ $$f"(-2)=0$$
example being
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+3}}{(2n+1)!}$$
What is f'''(0) =
$$f'''(0)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  (-1)^n\frac{(2n+3)(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(2n+1)!}0^{2n}$$
since 0^2n dominates the function. they used the first value of n which is n=0
the function then became
$$= 1.\frac{3.2.1}{1!}{0^0}$$ $$=6.1$$ $$f'''(0)=6$$ since$$ 0^0 = 1 $$
source for the example is https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-10-15/v/differentiating-power-series

Could you walk us through how you got to $f'(x)$? Keep in mind that $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$

It should be clear from the definition of $f$ that, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $f^{(n)}(-2)\ne0$.

I suspect you get $0$ because, when you differentiate you get $f'(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{n+2}{2^{3n}}(x+2)^{n-1}$ and you immediately plug in $x=-2$. (In your case, you're computing the second derivative, but the nature of the mistake is the same)

I’m voting to close this question because the OP has abandoned it.

I feel like a half hour wait is a bit hasty for an assumption of the question being abandoned. A few days maybe.

Thank you for the response my thought was i had to differentitate it twice and plug in x=-2 so i didnt quite know what to do instead

In fact, $f'(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{n+2}{2^{3n}}(x+2)^{n-1}= \frac{(1+2)(2+x)^{1-1}}{1\times2^{3\times1}} +\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n+2}{2^{3n}}(x+2)^{n-1} = \frac 3 8+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n+2}{2^{3n}}(x+2)^{n-1}$ and $f'(-2) = \frac 3 8 \ne 0$. If you do the same operation to get $f''(x)$ you will again find a non null term (for $n=2$...).

The mistake is that $(x+2)^0=1$ and then you plug in $x=-2$, in the whole series there'll be a single term without the x factor and that would be the second derivative at $x=-2$

Using Taylor series,  the coefficient of the second term is, on the one hand, $f''(-2)/2!,$ and on the other $(2+2)/(2\cdot 2^{3\cdot2}).$
So $f''(-2)=2\cdot 1/2^5=1/16.$

"$f'(x)=\frac{(n+2)(x+2)^{n-1}}{(2^{3n})}$" and "$f''(x)=\frac{(n+2)(n-1)(x+2)^{n-1}}{(2^{3n})}$" make no sense.
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(n+2)(x+2)^{n-1}}{2^{3n}}$$
$$f''(x)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(n+2)(n-1)(x+2)^{n-2}}{2^{3n}}=\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{(n+2)(n-1)(x+2)^{n-2}}{2^{3n}}.$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}f''(-2)&=\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{(n+2)(n-1)0^{n-2}}{2^{3n}}\\=&\frac{(2+2)(2-1)0^0}{2^6}+\sum_{n\ge3}\frac{(n+2)(n-1)0^{n-2}}{2^{3n}}\\&=\frac1{16}+0.\end{align}$$

thank you so much i didnt realise the first value of the Summation increases by 1 when you differentiate it so didnt realised it mattered to keep it their
the (x+2)^n-1 was a typo i ment to have (x+2)^n-2

I didn't notice the typo. What I wanted to insist on was the $\sum$ signs missing. The first value of the summation index remains $1$ in $f'(x)$, and can be set indifferently equal to $1$ or $2$ in $f''(x)$, since when $n=1$, $\frac{(n+2)(n-1)(x+2)^{n-2}}{2^{3n}}=\frac{3\cdot0(x+2)^{-1}}8=0(x+2)^{-1}=0$.

$0^0?$  written this way it isn't correct.   Just note that $f''$ has a constant term.  $f'$ should start at $n=2,$ and $f''$ at $n=3.$  Again,  $0(x+2)^{-1}$ isn't going to work at $x=-2.$

I agree to disagree with each of these claims.

To do this you'd need $50$k, so probably have to wait until tomorrow or so

? See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agree_to_disagree
